# Will Appium with XCUItest driver create xcuitest scripts for me?

Tags: ios, appium, visual-studio-app-center, xcuitest

This is my first time trying to test my Cordova iOS app to within AppCenter.  I've read documentation and it appears for UI testing on iOS hybrid apps I should use XCUITest framework so that is what I'm doing.

I set it all up and I started the test recording that is supposed to create the scripts for me but it crashes XCode and I'll spare you the details but I can't find the fix.  So now I'm forced to manually create my tests in order to upload to AppCenter.  Obviously I can manually create the tests and I've started doing that now but I'm not getting anywhere fast.

My question is: will Appium help me write XCUITests that I can then turn around and use to upload to AppCenter?  I started trying to implement Appium but so many areas of the documentation is a struggle for me.  I'll go back to trying to implement Appium if I know for a fact it will create the XCUITests for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Appium XCUITest driver uses a client-server architecture and sends commands to a device on the fly without generating XCTest-based code.